# Table of content page using UIKit

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, getuikit

I am using UIKit to develop a page where I have table of content floating on the right and the text on the left which surrounds the table of content (screenshot as below). I have  successfully developed the page so far. However, I am having a tough time to make this page responsive to all devices. I want my table of content stacked on the top and the the article should be underneath that on the smaller devices and on large device the table of content on the right and text on the left. Following is the code I am working on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="uk-container uk-padding uk-margin-medium-bottom ">
        <article class="uk-article">
            <div class="uk-width-xxlarge uk-margin-auto uk-text-center">
                <h1 class="uk-article-title">Security </h1>
            </div>

            <div class="toc uk-float-right uk-margin-left uk-margin-bottom uk-margin-top ">
                <h4 style="margin:0px">
                    <b>Contents</b>
                </h4>
                <hr>

                <!-- Table of content list starts from here -->
                <ul class="listOfContent">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#introduction">Introduction</a>
                        <ul>
                            <a href="#overview" class="uk-scroll"><li>Overview</li></a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <!--Introduction finsih here -->
                    <li>Contents</li>
                    <li><a href="#infra">Infrastructure Security</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Datacenters
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Availability and Resiliency</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li> Configuration Management
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Patching Policy</li>
                                    <li>Server Authentication</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>Monitoring</li>
                            <li>Automated Scanning
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Vulnerablity Scanning</li>
                                    <li>Intrusion Detection</li>
                                    <li>Data Leak Scanning</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!--Infrastructure Secuirty finish here -->
                    <li>Data Security
                        <ul>
                            <li>Privacy</li>
                            <li>Data Sovereignty
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Leaving the Org</li>
                                </ul>
                                <li>Support Access</li>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!--Data Secuirty list close here -->

                    <li>Web Application Secuirty
                        <ul>
                            <li>Change Management
                                <ul>
                                    <li>CI/CD</li>
                                    <li>Testing</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>User Authentication
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Password Storage</li>
                                    <li>Password Requirements</li>
                                    <li>Google Authentication Support
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Two/Multi-factor Authentication</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>Encryption
                                <ul>
                                    <li>HTTPS/TLS</li>
                                    <li>Encryption in Transit</li>
                                    <li>Encryption at Rest</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!--Web application list finishes here -->

                    <li>Network Secuirty
                        <ul>
                            <li>Firewalls</li>
                            <li>Network Flow Monitoring</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Network finsihes here -->
                    <li>Backups and Business Continuity</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Database Backups
                            <ul>
                                <li>Ppint In Time Recovery via Automated Backups</li>
                                <li> Cross Region Copied Snapshots</li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                        <li>Other Backups</li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--Start of the article -->
            <div class=" uk-align-center uk-flex-first@l uk-flex-first@m uk-flex-last@s ">
                <div>
                    <span class="anchor" id="introduction"></span>
                    <!-- <div class="introduction"> -->
                    <h3 >Introduction</h3>
                    <p class="uk-article-lead"> This Company is a SaaS platform used to collect and analyse customer feedback and survey. development team is based in Germany<br/> <br/>
                    This is a collection of topics that describe how we run securely. They're intended as a high-level introduction to how we deal with security, in order to help you with your decision making process. More details are available on request - just ask your sales representative.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!--Overview div -->
                <div>
                    <h3>Overview</h3>

                    <p> As a very high-level summary:
                        <ul>
                            <li>The Company has strong application, network and infrastructure-level security controls in place to ensure your data is safely stored and processed
                            <br/><br/></li>
                            <li>Comaony serves multiple tenants from the same application codebase, but uses effective isolation techniques to keep tenant data separate
                            <br/><br/></li>
                            <li>Comopany observes privacy laws, which are broadly compatible with many other jurisdictions (for example, we support the rights of access and rectification for data subjects)
                            <br/>
                            <br/></li>
                            <li>Company is hosted on AWS, in multiple regions, using VPC
                            You'll find more information on each of these points in the detailed chapters documents below. <br/></br></li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <!--divider style="overflow: hidden;" -->
                <hr style="overflow: hidden;">

                <!-- Infrastructure Div -->

                <div>
                    <span class="anchor" id="infra"></span>
                    <h3>Infrastructure Security</h3>
                    <h5 id="datacenters" style="margin-bottom:0px;"><b>Datacenters </b></h5>
                    <p>
                        Company's products are hosted with the world’s leading data centre provider, Amazon Web Services (AWS). Access to these datacenters is strictly controlled and monitored by 24x7 on-site security staff, biometric scanning and video surveillance.
                        AWS maintains multiple certifications for its data centres, including ISO 27001 compliance, PCI Certification, and SOC reports. For more information about their certification and compliance, please visit the AWS Security website and the AWS Compliance website.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
                <br/>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: SCREEN SHOT]

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your code, there are also some html errors, so be sure to check your code too.

You can override the behaviour of your TOC by `!important` rules but it can cause problems or in some cases, won't work because there are other rules in UIKit using `!important`, so it's better to create your own custom class and apply this behaviour to it.

I've created a `.custom-toc` class, which basically replicates `.uk-float-right` and `.uk-margin-left` and when the screen width is lower than X, remove these rules..

For this snippet, I've set the `max-width` to 768px, so when on preview, TOC is on top, when you click on 'Full page', you'll get TOC on the right ..

```css
/* assign a lower value, something between 480 and 568 should be fine */
.custom-toc {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .custom-toc {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.35/css/uikit.min.css" />

<div class="uk-container uk-padding uk-margin-medium-bottom ">
  <article class="uk-article">
    <div class="uk-width-xxlarge uk-margin-auto uk-text-center">
      <h1 class="uk-article-title">Security </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="toc custom-toc uk-margin-bottom uk-margin-top ">
      <h4 style="margin:0px">
        <b>Contents</b>
      </h4>
      <hr>

      <!-- Table of content list starts from here -->
      <ul class="listOfContent">
        <li>
          <a href="#introduction">Introduction</a>
          <ul>
            <a href="#overview" class="uk-scroll">
              <li>Overview</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <!--Introduction finsih here -->
        <li>Contents</li>
        <li><a href="#infra">Infrastructure Security</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Datacenters
              <ul>
                <li>Availability and Resiliency</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li> Configuration Management
              <ul>
                <li>Patching Policy</li>
                <li>Server Authentication</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Monitoring</li>
            <li>Automated Scanning
              <ul>
                <li>Vulnerablity Scanning</li>
                <li>Intrusion Detection</li>
                <li>Data Leak Scanning</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!--Infrastructure Secuirty finish here -->
        <li>Data Security
          <ul>
            <li>Privacy</li>
            <li>Data Sovereignty
              <ul>
                <li>Leaving the Org</li>
                <li>Support Access</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!--Data Secuirty list close here -->

        <li>Web Application Secuirty
          <ul>
            <li>Change Management
              <ul>
                <li>CI/CD</li>
                <li>Testing</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>User Authentication
              <ul>
                <li>Password Storage</li>
                <li>Password Requirements</li>
                <li>Google Authentication Support
                  <ul>
                    <li>Two/Multi-factor Authentication</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Encryption
              <ul>
                <li>HTTPS/TLS</li>
                <li>Encryption in Transit</li>
                <li>Encryption at Rest</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!--Web application list finishes here -->

        <li>Network Secuirty
          <ul>
            <li>Firewalls</li>
            <li>Network Flow Monitoring</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- Network finsihes here -->
        <li>Backups and Business Continuity</li>
        <ul>
          <li>Database Backups
            <ul>
              <li>Ppint In Time Recovery via Automated Backups</li>
              <li> Cross Region Copied Snapshots</li>
            </ul>

          </li>
          <li>Other Backups</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--Start of the article -->
    <div class=" uk-align-center uk-flex-first@l uk-flex-first@m uk-flex-last@s ">
      <div>
        <span class="anchor" id="introduction"></span>
        <!-- <div class="introduction"> -->
        <h3>Introduction</h3>
        <p class="uk-article-lead"> This Company is a SaaS platform used to collect and analyse customer feedback and survey. development team is based in Germany<br/> <br/> This is a collection of topics that describe how we run securely. They're intended as a high-level introduction
          to how we deal with security, in order to help you with your decision making process. More details are available on request - just ask your sales representative.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!--Overview div -->
      <div>
        <h3>Overview</h3>

        <p> As a very high-level summary: </p>
        <ul>
          <li>The Company has strong application, network and infrastructure-level security controls in place to ensure your data is safely stored and processed
          </li>
          <li>Comaony serves multiple tenants from the same application codebase, but uses effective isolation techniques to keep tenant data separate
          </li>
          <li>Comopany observes privacy laws, which are broadly compatible with many other jurisdictions (for example, we support the rights of access and rectification for data subjects)
          </li>
          <li>Company is hosted on AWS, in multiple regions, using VPC You'll find more information on each of these points in the detailed chapters documents below.
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!--divider style="overflow: hidden;" -->
      <hr style="overflow: hidden;">

      <!-- Infrastructure Div -->

      <div>
        <span class="anchor" id="infra"></span>
        <h3>Infrastructure Security</h3>
        <h5 id="datacenters" style="margin-bottom:0px;"><b>Datacenters </b></h5>
        <p>
          Company's products are hosted with the world’s leading data centre provider, Amazon Web Services (AWS). Access to these datacenters is strictly controlled and monitored by 24x7 on-site security staff, biometric scanning and video surveillance. AWS maintains
          multiple certifications for its data centres, including ISO 27001 compliance, PCI Certification, and SOC reports. For more information about their certification and compliance, please visit the AWS Security website and the AWS Compliance website.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
          adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
          velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
          non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- </div> -->
      <br/>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Or if you want to use only UIKit classes, you can use `.uk-align-right@s` or `.uk-align-right@m` which will apply that class only on specified width and it combines float and margin too (but sometimes it's hard to fine tune it, so I prefer custom classes, 640px for `@s` is something between mobile and tablet ..). Here I used `@m` just to demonstrate behaviour better in the snippet, in your code, you should use `@s`

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.35/css/uikit.min.css" />

<div class="uk-container uk-padding uk-margin-medium-bottom ">
  <article class="uk-article">
    <div class="uk-width-xxlarge uk-margin-auto uk-text-center">
      <h1 class="uk-article-title">Security </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="toc uk-align-right@s uk-margin-bottom uk-margin-top">
      <h4 style="margin:0px">
        <b>Contents</b>
      </h4>
      <hr>

      <!-- Table of content list starts from here -->
      <ul class="listOfContent">
        <li>
          <a href="#introduction">Introduction</a>
          <ul>
            <a href="#overview" class="uk-scroll">
              <li>Overview</li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <!--Introduction finsih here -->
        <li>Contents</li>
        <li><a href="#infra">Infrastructure Security</a>
          <ul>
            <li>Datacenters
              <ul>
                <li>Availability and Resiliency</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li> Configuration Management
              <ul>
                <li>Patching Policy</li>
                <li>Server Authentication</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Monitoring</li>
            <li>Automated Scanning
              <ul>
                <li>Vulnerablity Scanning</li>
                <li>Intrusion Detection</li>
                <li>Data Leak Scanning</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!--Infrastructure Secuirty finish here -->
        <li>Data Security
          <ul>
            <li>Privacy</li>
            <li>Data Sovereignty
              <ul>
                <li>Leaving the Org</li>
                <li>Support Access</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!--Data Secuirty list close here -->

        <li>Web Application Secuirty
          <ul>
            <li>Change Management
              <ul>
                <li>CI/CD</li>
                <li>Testing</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>User Authentication
              <ul>
                <li>Password Storage</li>
                <li>Password Requirements</li>
                <li>Google Authentication Support
                  <ul>
                    <li>Two/Multi-factor Authentication</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Encryption
              <ul>
                <li>HTTPS/TLS</li>
                <li>Encryption in Transit</li>
                <li>Encryption at Rest</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!--Web application list finishes here -->

        <li>Network Secuirty
          <ul>
            <li>Firewalls</li>
            <li>Network Flow Monitoring</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- Network finsihes here -->
        <li>Backups and Business Continuity</li>
        <ul>
          <li>Database Backups
            <ul>
              <li>Ppint In Time Recovery via Automated Backups</li>
              <li> Cross Region Copied Snapshots</li>
            </ul>

          </li>
          <li>Other Backups</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--Start of the article -->
    <div class=" uk-align-center uk-flex-first@l uk-flex-first@m uk-flex-last@s ">
      <div>
        <span class="anchor" id="introduction"></span>
        <!-- <div class="introduction"> -->
        <h3>Introduction</h3>
        <p class="uk-article-lead"> This Company is a SaaS platform used to collect and analyse customer feedback and survey. development team is based in Germany<br/> <br/> This is a collection of topics that describe how we run securely. They're intended as a high-level introduction
          to how we deal with security, in order to help you with your decision making process. More details are available on request - just ask your sales representative.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!--Overview div -->
      <div>
        <h3>Overview</h3>

        <p> As a very high-level summary: </p>
        <ul>
          <li>The Company has strong application, network and infrastructure-level security controls in place to ensure your data is safely stored and processed
          </li>
          <li>Comaony serves multiple tenants from the same application codebase, but uses effective isolation techniques to keep tenant data separate
          </li>
          <li>Comopany observes privacy laws, which are broadly compatible with many other jurisdictions (for example, we support the rights of access and rectification for data subjects)
          </li>
          <li>Company is hosted on AWS, in multiple regions, using VPC You'll find more information on each of these points in the detailed chapters documents below.
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!--divider style="overflow: hidden;" -->
      <hr style="overflow: hidden;">

      <!-- Infrastructure Div -->

      <div>
        <span class="anchor" id="infra"></span>
        <h3>Infrastructure Security</h3>
        <h5 id="datacenters" style="margin-bottom:0px;"><b>Datacenters </b></h5>
        <p>
          Company's products are hosted with the world’s leading data centre provider, Amazon Web Services (AWS). Access to these datacenters is strictly controlled and monitored by 24x7 on-site security staff, biometric scanning and video surveillance. AWS maintains
          multiple certifications for its data centres, including ISO 27001 compliance, PCI Certification, and SOC reports. For more information about their certification and compliance, please visit the AWS Security website and the AWS Compliance website.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
          adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
          velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
          incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
          non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- </div> -->
      <br/>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First: stick your toc-block on the left side and the text on the right side (= mobile first approach).
Then try this: https://getuikit.com/docs/align#responsive

Comment: the top block is the Table of Content which needs to be float on the right